# Are there any limit on android for xml file?

Tags: android, xml

---

### Are there any limit on android for xml file ?

I have so many xml file in my Android project, it's because I am not using Database for my data so i put each data in one *XML* file and intent to it and i need even more XML cause my data increases, im afraid it will affect performance, so the questions is:

1. there are any limit on android for XML file?
2. will it affect the app performance?
3. is it available to make more than a hundred XML file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No there is no limit.
2. No it will not affect your app performance.
3. Yes

Comment: is it possible to encounter `resource compilation failed` while building the app if strings.xml has more than 31 thousand lines?

Answer (score 0):

Decompile after apk build and you will get the answer.

Perhaps the resource is occupying a lot of ROM.

I do not know whether performance is memory related or speed related, but I think there is a problem.

However, when you want to optimize memory-related performance, you can try optimizing with the [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code), [App bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/).

Comment: don't think you can optimise xml files with proguard/ app bundle have nothing to do with xml files

Comment: My answer did not seem to clean. Yes I know. just If the ROM usage has increased, told that how to reduce the ROM size of apk. Proguard and App bundle obviously solving other causes, but it can boost memory performance.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limit it could be very large and I don't think you will reach it easily. And NO, it doesn't affects performance because those XML files are not read by Android until your code explicitly reads them. Maybe the compilation time (during development) and the installation time could be increased, but it doesn't not affect performance in runtime execution.

Comment: is it possible to encounter `resource compilation failed` while building the app if strings.xml has more than 31 thousand lines?